# Scroll bar is not padding in <div> with 'overflow' style

Tags: css, html

I'm very new in frontend world (I did html in 99 year... many changes since that time...)
Example of sourse is here: 
    `css code`https://jsfiddle.net/titan83/bm13dqyy/1/
You can see that vertical scrollbar is sticked to top element (combobox). Howewer the table in problem  have a right position.
How to force scrollbar to be aligned like table?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **force scrollbar to be aligned like table?**

Comment: this make no sense!

Answer (score 1):

Got your issue, give `margin-top: 10px` instead of `padding-top: 10px` to the `div` with `overflow`

```html
      <select id="SGroups" onchange="onSGroupChanged(this.value)" style="width: 100%"></select>
      <div style="height:80vh; overflow: scroll; margin-top: 10px;">
        <table id="worksheetTable">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```